# Homomorphism keeps zero divisors, the unit maps to unit?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $R,S\neq \{0\}$ be a rings and let $\varphi:R\to S$ be a rings homomorphism **onto** on $S$. Prove or disprove with counter example:
>
> A. if there is a unit in $R$ then $\varphi(1_R)=1_S$
>
> B. if $R$ has zero divisors then there is for $S$ zero divisors

*Attempt:*

A. Correct, for all $b$ in $S$ there is $a$ such that $\varphi(a)=b$ therefore $b=\varphi(a)=\varphi(1_r a)=\varphi(1_R)\varphi(a)=\overbrace{\varphi(1_R)}^{\text{unit in } S}b$

B.I thought to say something like this: $2,3$ are zero divisors in $\mathbb Z_6$ now to find a map $\varphi: \mathbb Z_6\to \text{ some ring without zero divisors}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* You're almost there. Consider the canonical projection $\mathbb Z_6 \to \mathbb Z_2$ or $\mathbb Z_3$.